# Is there an Apache tuner script like mysqltuner.pl?

Tags: performance, http, optimization, apache

My httpd connections are using too much memory and I'd like to fix it. [MySQLTuner.pl](http://mysqltuner.pl/mysqltuner.pl) is a fantastic little script to do something similar for MySQL. Is there something like this available for Apache?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- [apachetuner.sh](https://github.com/gusmaskowitz/apachetuner) (for RedHat only)
- [apachebuddy.pl](https://github.com/gusmaskowitz/apachebuddy.pl)

could be helpful.

Comment: how do you use them for those of us that are still green with linux command line stuff.  Could you write the steps out please?  Cheers

Comment: solved it my self.. you can use curl to make run it.. on possible way is "perl <(curl http://cloudfiles.fanatassist.com/apachebuddy.pl)"  --- in side the quotes ;)

Comment: Got anything for Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 4):

Both apachetuner.sh and apachebuddy.pl are now out of date.

The most recent version of this is apache2buddy.pl (https://github.com/richardforth/apache2buddy).

Answer (score 2):

By naitan's answer I checked for apache tuner and apache buddy which were written by same person. They don't seem help too much. Very limited when compared to mysqltuner or mysql primer's capabilites. You can use them like this:

```
# cd /opt
# wget https://raw.github.com/gusmaskowitz/apachebuddy.pl/master/apachebuddy.pl
# chmod +x apachebuddy.pl
# wget https://raw.github.com/gusmaskowitz/apachetuner/master/apachetuner.sh
# chmod +x apachetuner.sh

# /opt/apachebuddy.pl
# /opt/apachetuner.sh
```